# Maven copying applicationContext.xml from src/main/resources to target/myproject/WEB-INF

Tags: java, spring, maven, applicationcontext

At the moment, the default I think, it copies to

```
target/myproject/WEB-INF/classes
```

so when deploying it does not pick up the context.

Also, i want to reference a server specific config file *database.properties*, I want to put it in tomcat/conf and then reference it in *applicationContext.xml*, how can I do this ?

Also(2), I am under the impression that this is a fairly standard and decent way to set things up - please correct me if I am wrong.

*edit*
for the server specific config file I user this

```
<context:property-placeholder 
      location="file:${catalina.home}/conf/database.properties" 
      ignore-unresolvable="true"
 />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your title question: Often in a .war maven module, you'll put web related resources under src/main/webapp instead of src/main/resources.  Then the maven plugin will pick them up automatically because it matches convention.  So, move your applicationContext.xml to src/main/webapp/WEB-INF

Another option is to configure the webResources as described in the [documentation](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/examples/adding-filtering-webresources.html)

For the second question you can look at a [PropertyPlaceHolderConfigurer](http://www.mkyong.com/spring/spring-propertyplaceholderconfigurer-example/). You'll just have to get the path correct.

Comment: I thought the convention was putting it in src/main/resources, and for testing I can put a different one in src/test/resources

Comment: That's convention for a jar module, and even then they are put within classes because that determines the content of the jar file.  For webapp resources that should end up within the webapp structure and not in classes you put them in src/main/webapp and they are pulled unto a matching directory structure with the root of your .war file.  So src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/spring/config/context.xml would end up in WEB-INF/spring/config/context.xml within your .war file.

Comment: The other option is to configure the webResources.  I've updated my answer with a link to that documentation.

Answer (score 6):

If you need to keep `applicationContext.xml` as a classpath resource, you can configure `ContextLoaderListener` to pick it from the classpath by adding the following lines to `web.xml`:

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>classpath:applicationContext.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
```

It's much easier than configuring Maven to copy it to `WEB-INF`.

Regarding the second question, you can configure `PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer` or `<context:property-placeholder>` to load `.properties` file from a file system.